# Can I combine a "classic" css rule with a media query containing the same styles?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm wondering if I can combine 2 rules applied on the same element and containing the same styles but one of the rules is in a media query and get something similar to :

```
.a,
.b .a {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

The rules are :

- Apply colors to the `.content` depending on the `prefers-color-scheme`,
- Change the `.content` colors when an `input` is `checked`

```css
:root {
  --dark-color: white;
  --dark-bg: black;
  --light-color: black;
  --light-bg: white;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .content {
    color: var(--dark-color);
    background-color: var(--dark-bg);
  }
}
#dark-theme:checked~.content {
  color: var(--dark-color);
  background-color: var(--dark-bg);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  .content {
    color: var(--light-color);
    background-color: var(--light-bg);
  }
}
#light-theme:checked~.content {
  color: var(--light-color);
  background-color: var(--light-bg);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="color-theme" id="dark-theme">
<label for="dark-theme">dark</label>
<input type="radio" name="color-theme" id="light-theme">
<label for="light-theme">light</label>
<input type="radio" name="color-theme" id="default-theme" checked>
<label for="default-theme">default</label>

<div class="content">Test</div>
```

Here `.content` will get a black background and a white color if the `prefer-color-scheme` is dark, or if `#dark-theme` is checked.

The same styles are applied for both rules.

Is there a way to combine these rules ?

Comment: Looks like `#dark-theme:checked~.content` outweighs `.content` inside the media query. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: And I'm happy with that, I just need both : the media query by default, the `:checked` option so a user can change the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with native CSS. However, if your question is related to less writing, this need is already covered by CSS compilers.
If you are willing to try, this is the code in a simple way written with Sass.

First, you can wrap the content in a `@mixin`. It will store your class with a variable for the area it should change depending on the selected theme.

```css
@mixin content-style($theme) {
  .content {
    color: var(--#{$theme}-color);
    background-color: var(--#{$theme}-bg);
  }
}
```

After that, you can use it inside another mixin to define the themes styles:

```css
@mixin themed-style($theme) {
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: $theme) {
    @include content-style($theme);
  }
  ##{$theme}-theme:checked ~ {
   @include content-style(#{$theme});
  }
}
```

and finally you can use it to create as many themes just changing the variable:

```css
@include themed-style(dark);
@include themed-style(light);
```

If you want to see the output, which is same than your original code, you can try it [here](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Complete Code to copy-paste to see the conversion:

```css
:root {
    --dark-color: white;
    --dark-bg: black;
    --light-color: black;
    --light-bg: white;
}

@mixin content-style($theme) {
  .content {
    color: var(--#{$theme}-color);
    background-color: var(--#{$theme}-bg);
  }
}

@mixin themed-style($theme) {
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: $theme) {
    @include content-style($theme);
  }
  ##{$theme}-theme:checked ~ {
   @include content-style(#{$theme});
  }
}

@include themed-style(dark);
@include themed-style(light);
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
:root {
  --dark-color: white;
  --dark-bg: black;
  --light-color: black;
  --light-bg: white;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  #default-theme:checked~.content {
    color: var(--dark-color);
    background-color: var(--dark-bg);
  }
}
#dark-theme:checked~.content {
  color: var(--dark-color);
  background-color: var(--dark-bg);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  #default-theme:checked~.content {
    color: var(--light-color);
    background-color: var(--light-bg);
  }
}
#light-theme:checked~.content {
  color: var(--light-color);
  background-color: var(--light-bg);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="color-theme" id="dark-theme">
<label for="dark-theme">dark</label>
<input type="radio" name="color-theme" id="light-theme">
<label for="light-theme">light</label>
<input type="radio" name="color-theme" id="default-theme" checked>
<label for="default-theme">default</label>

<div class="content">Test</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I edited it to try to be more clear